# Showing interstital ad on button click

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

So in my LIBGDX game I want to show Interstital ad when the button is clicked, for example, a button to restart game.

In the class where I have that button I've set up this globally:

```
 AdControlller adController;


    public MainMenu(AdControlller adController) {
        this.adController = adController;
    }
```

And then in touchUp method for the button I'm setting this:

```
public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                howToPlayButton.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(1, 1,.1f));
                mainMenu.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(0.24f),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (adController.isNetworkConnected()) {
                            adController.showInterstitalAd(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    game.setScreen(new HowToPlay(game));
                                    loopMusic.dispose();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                })));

            }
        });
```

The problem is, when I click on the button it gaves me this logcat error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 148306
                                                                Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 30808
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.mygdx.game.AdControlller.isNetworkConnected()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.mygdx.game.screens.MainMenu$5$1.run(MainMenu.java:167)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.run(RunnableAction.java:42)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.act(RunnableAction.java:32)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction.act(SequenceAction.java:65)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.act(Actor.java:95)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:46)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:222)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:186)
                                                                    at com.mygdx.game.screens.MainMenu.render(MainMenu.java:267)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
                                                                    at com.mygdx.game.Main.render(Main.java:37)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474)
                                                                    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
                                                                    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

What am I doing wrong?

IS NETWORK CONNECTED METHOD

```
@Override
    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

Comment: check if `adController` is null ?

Comment: Can you check and see if `adController` is null ? It seems that `adController` is not initialized so it is giving **NPE**

Comment: If i type if (adController != null) { before if (adController.isNetworkConnected()) { I only get black screen that's not loading scene

Comment: That means your `adController` is null, check if you are properly initializing it

Comment: What do you exactly mean?  Tried everything I know, can't get it working. If I paste code above in my Main game's class render method interstital ad pops up every two seconds and if you close it the new one appears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111286/discussion-between-satyen-udeshi-and-daxhr).